# userFunc in TYPO3 TCA showing "Class Not Found" error

Tags: forms, typo3

I have a form in the backend in TYPO3 6.1.0. There is a field in the form to which I want to render some HTML content from a class. I did some research and found `user` and `userFunc` will help me do that.

However, when I try that, I get `Class Not Found` exception.

The php code for display TCA is as follows:

```
'status' => array(
            'exclude' => 0,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:calendar/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_calendar_domain_model_display.status',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'user',
                'userFunc' => 'EXT:calendar/class.tx_calendars_tca.php:tx_calendars_tca->someWizard',
                'params' => array('color' => 'green'),
                ),
        ),
```

My extension is called `Calendar` and is located in `typo3conf/ext/calendar` folder. In this folder I have my class file `class.tx_calendars_tca.php`.

I used `extension_builder` to create the extension.

Somehow, the class is not getting linked. Shows me `Class Not Found` error!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code to the **ext_tables.php** file of your extension:

```
if(TYPO3_MODE == 'BE') {
  require_once(t3lib_extMgm::extPath($_EXTKEY).'class.tx_calendars_tca.php');
}
```

You can then in your TCA config set `userFunc` to `tx_calendars_tca->someWizard` only.

Comment: Thanks. It's working now. You seem to be having experience on TYPO3, can you look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16829737/typo3-extension-to-be-listed-under-web-list as well ? Thank You

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem. @cascaval I added your code to the file, but it still shows me the same No Class Found error.

Comment: Hmm... Are you sure you are adding the correct file and that the class is named the way you specify in the `userFunc`? Because otherwise I have no idea why it wouldn't work.

Comment: The problem was `namespace`. If I `DO NOT` specify any namespace it works Perfect, otherwise shows all kinds of errors!