# TYPO3 extension to be listed under "Web" list

Tags: typo3, backend

I have an extension created using extension builder. The TYPO3 version is 6.1.0. Just like we have the `news` extension in TYPO3, I would like my extension to also be shown under the `Web` list. Can custom extensions be displayed like this ?

I want my extension to be listed under `Web` but Of course it should also be listed under List>Page... But by having the extension listed here, I can have all the records of this extension under one tab.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: What you are talking about is a backend module. Your extension can have it as well but you have to understand that what tt_news does with its **News Admin** is not some core functionality. You would have to implement it yourself. Look at **tt_news/mod1/index.php** to see how the tt_news extension implements it.

Answer (score 1):

You created your `BE module` with Extension Builder, didn't you ? It has a possibility to choose the 'Main module' - `web`, which is default btw.

If you registered your module manually, just set the second param of `Tx_Extbase_Utility_Extension::registerModule` to `web`. Other options are: `user`, `tools`, `help`.

**Edit**

You **need to add the BE module** - that's actually what you want to do. `Extension Builder` doesn't create any 'TYPO3 BE typical' view for BE modules, so you need to create it yourself.

Additionally most probably you will need to add new separated `action` or better even `controller` dedicated for this BE module, so there you'll use another views as well.

For an example there are some  ViewHelpers for usage in BE modules, one of them is: `TableListViewHelper` (*note: it's from 4.x, I dont' know if it present in 6.x too*).

Comment: Well, I only created a FE plugin. If I create the BE plugin, It displays the `Default View` that is List.html of the extension and not the set of all records.

Comment: Thanks. Will do that and check :)

Comment: Take a look at the news extension from Georg Ringer. It includes a backend module and many other extbase features. Also take look at the belog and beuser modules. They are both full extbase modules.